# Trying to parse a git log file in a very particular way using git log commands and python

Tags: python, git-log

I want to display only the diff between commits that have a tag added to them. Or the closest to this. In other words something like this:

```
tag  "5 ..."
@@ -1,1 +1,3 @@
+ dfd
+ dfgd

tag "4.."
@@ -1,1 +1,3 @@
+ dfd
+ dfgd
```

And so on. I have tried but cannot get this specific format maybe someone can help me out there. Then once I have a text file with this format or as close as possible I do the following:

```
with open('log_output_alex.txt', 'r') as f:
  read_data = f.read()
f.closed

tag_separation = read_data.split('tag: "')
```

After doing this I do not know how TO READ EACH OF THE LINES IN EACH OF THE STRINGS in the array tag_separation?

Once I can do this I can check if line in the string starts with a certain character (@, +, - or tag) and store different lines in data structures to manipulate later.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use [the `GitPython`library](http://packages.python.org/GitPython/0.3.1/tutorial.html), which will give you an higher-level access to your `git` repository.

And even if you decide not to use it, you can probably have a look at how it's done there!

Answer (score 0):

Git won’t be able to give you that format in a single command, so you need to create it yourself a bit. For that, here are some hints:

- You can get a list of tags using `git tag`
- You can get the commit SHA1 for a reference (i.e. tag) using `git rev-parse TAGNAME`
- You can get the diff between two commits using `git diff A..B`, for example `git diff tag1..tag2`

That way you also end up with already separated diffs for each tag, so you do not need to store it in a file first and split it again, you can just start with it.

> After doing this I do not know *how to read each of the lines in each of the strings*

You can iterate through the lines of a string by splitting it first, using [`str.splitlines`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines).